# PHP How to create real hex values from a string

Tags: php, casting, hex, sha1

I have a string with hexvalues that I use with sha1()

```
echo sha1("\x23\x9A\xB9\xCB\x28\x2D\xAF\x66\x23\x1D\xC5\xA4\xDF\x6B\xFB\xAE\x00\x00\x00\x01");

ab94fcedf2664edfb9b291f85d7f77f27f2f4a9d
```

now I have another string with the same value only not hex.

```
$string2=strtoupper("239ab9cb282daf66231dc5a4df6bfbae00000001");
```

I want to convert this string so that it is read as above and that the sha1-value is the same as above.

```
echo sha1(do_something($string2));

ab94fcedf2664edfb9b291f85d7f77f27f2f4a9d
```

Does anybody know how to convert a string to real hexvalues?

I've tried with *pack*, *sprinft*, *hexdec*, but nothing worked (couldn't find *typecasting* in hex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$s = "239ab9cb282daf66231dc5a4df6bfbae00000001";
echo sha1(pack('H*', $s));
```

Output:

```
ab94fcedf2664edfb9b291f85d7f77f27f2f4a9d
```